# Identify comic book story about alien who lived several lives

Tags: story-identification, marvel, dc

I read the story in the '50s.

The story was probably in a DC comic.

A college professor uses hypnosis to discover people's past lives (like Bridey Murphy). He discovers that one of his subjects is an alien android who lived as many historic leaders. His last life before the present was Adolph Hitler. His current life is as a custodian at the college.

I misled Trish by failing to say: this was not a superhero comic. It was a 'one and done' story in a science fiction/fantasy/adventure anthology.

I'd like to identify the story so that I can find more of the author's work.

Comment: Hmmm...well there is a DC supervillain ([Vandal Savage](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Adg_%28New_Earth%29)) who claimed to have ruled hundreds of civilizations under hundreds of names, e.g. Khafre, Alexander the Great, Julius Caesar, Genghis Khan, and Vlad the Impaler. He had also worked as close friends and advisers to the likes of Erik the Red, Napoleon Bonaparte, Ra's al Ghul, Otto von Bismarck and Adolf Hitler. He even put Hitler in cryogenic suspension and took over as Fuhrer. But he was a Cro-Magnon transformed into an immortal by an asteroid, not an alien android.

Comment: Love the Starbucks spelling of Adolph. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might possibly be [Torquemada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torquemada_%28comics%29), the antagonist of *Nemesis the Warlock*.

> In fact, late in the series, it was revealed (through the actions of Thoth, son of Nemesis the Warlock) that his previous incarnations have included Colonel John M. Chivington, Witchfinder General Matthew Hopkins, Adolf Hitler, and his namesake, the original Torquemada. (He is, however, also a dedicated family man – he is distressed when Nemesis kills his children while escaping the Terminators, and loves his wife Candida to such an extent he consorts with aliens in an effort to prevent her from divorcing him.)

[Illustrations of the past life regression](http://2000adonline.tumblr.com/post/50935663490/the-many-lives-of-tomas-de-torquemada-tomas-de).